# Executing files from colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am using the darknet code for YOLO object detection. I have customized it for my dataset and it runs fine in my local computer. However when I uploaded the code to google drive and try to execute it from a new jupyter notebook in Colab using the code :

```
%shell ./darknet detector train custom_data/detector.data custom_data/cfg/yolov3-custom.cfg darknet53.conv.74 yolov3-custom
```

I get the error :

```
bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory
```

I am really stuck at this, any suggestions would be really helpful, thanks !

Comment: Where is the file./darknet ? Did you upload it to colab

Comment: Yes its a folder I uploaded to google drive, and darknet is an exec file.

Comment: I think colab is not able to execute the darknet file ( which is an exec)

Comment: Please check this link. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lTGZsfMaGUpBG4inDIQwIJVW476ibXk_    Make the configuration as explained and step 3 is your desired code. Ignore if already tried this.

Comment: Thanks, I too was referring the same link, but am not able to upload my full directory to github as they have done as my folder is larger than 100 MB.

Comment: Uploading a zip of the folder and unzipping it using `!unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/darknet.zip"` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a zip of the folder and unzipping it using

```
!unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/darknet.zip"
```

works as the folder now appears inside the `root` directory itself and not inside `content/drive/My Drive`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to import a file if it is too large:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload
```

This should allow you to download the file from your computer

Comment: Will it be downloaded permanently or will I lose it after I open by colab notebook again.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian I believe so, I definitely know it is in the colab files after so I would think so. Have you tried it?

Comment: I am only able to upload files using your code, how do I upload an entire directory ?

Comment: @SurajSubramanian Sorry, I do not really know. You can try zip the folder and then from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Comment: After you can then unzip it. !unzip -uq "/content/drive/My Drive/PATH_TO_ZIP" -d "/content/drive/My Drive/PATH_TO_OUTPUT". If this does not work you will have to keep looking I'm sorry